# Best Practice to send out list by different owner in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I'm trying to send **Monthly birthday list** to every store manager from SFMC.

I'm thinking that there might have 2 ways to achieve it though I'm still not quite sure how to complete it.

Is there any better suggestion?

Super Thanks in advance!

Victoria

---

**{Solution 1}**
/ in Automation Studio

Data Filter (Refresh monthly) > Data Export to FTP > Attach file in Email by AMP Script.

*And repeat 37 times as there's 37 stores...

**{Solution 2}**
/ in Automation Studio

Data Filter x37 (Refresh monthly)> [HTTP email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/gtlDataLookup.htm?search_text=export) x1 (AMPScript)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution!

Even no need to do filter x 37 and export!

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/suggestedCarListings.htm